# Exit SSH from the script

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, shell, ssh

I Want to exit ssh:

How does the below line work:

```
ssh -f -T ${USAGE_2_USER}@${USAGE_2_HOST}
```

Or do i need to write it some other way . Please tell should I use exit with ssh an how?

I am using ssh in my script .
I want to exit from it after the execution of it, with out showing them up in the proccess.

Comment: please edit your question and write in more details what you're doing and what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vauge, so I will answer it based on what you asked.

`ssh -f -T ${USAGE_2_USER}@${USAGE_2_HOST} ${CMD}`

this would ssh as the user assigned to `${USAGE_2_USER}` to the host assigned to `${USAGE_2_HOST}` and then run whatever you have assigned to `${CMD}` and then return the output and then exit.

```
risk@DockMaster:~$ ssh oracle@orc017a uptime
 13:17:41 up 9 days, 13:54,  7 users,  load average: 1.67, 2.19, 2.11
risk@DockMaster:~$
```

As a side note is the `-f -T` needed?